# Angular How to post Data By sequence of its object

Tags: javascript, angular

i have this kind of data  i want to post it by order from logframeActionStatusRefrenceId but the result is not in order 
how to dot it ????
Thanks for helping me in advance

```
  let status = [
      {
        id: 0,
        logicalFrameworkId: this.Data.logframeId,
        logFrameActionStatusReferenceId: 10,
        remarks: 'ACCEPTED->PBO-PPDO',
        actedByEIC: this.eic
      },
      {
        id: 0,
        logicalFrameworkId: this.Data.logframeId,
        logFrameActionStatusReferenceId: 12,
        remarks: 'ACCEPTED->INCLUSION',
        actedByEIC: this.eic
      }
    ];


HERE IS MY CODE  but the order of the post is in random

 status.forEach(data=> {
        console.log('data data data');
        console.log(data);
        console.log('data data data');
       return this.programService.saveStatus(data).subscribe(d=> {

       },error => {
         console.log(error);
       },() => {
         console.log("succesfully Save");
       })

    });
```

Comment: Please add some sample data to work with.

Comment: i updated it @SiddAjmera

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to sort it first before you send it. Something like this:

```
let status = [{
    id: 0,
    logicalFrameworkId: this.Data.logframeId,
    logFrameActionStatusReferenceId: 10,
    remarks: 'ACCEPTED->PBO-PPDO',
    actedByEIC: this.eic
  },
  {
    id: 0,
    logicalFrameworkId: this.Data.logframeId,
    logFrameActionStatusReferenceId: 12,
    remarks: 'ACCEPTED->INCLUSION',
    actedByEIC: this.eic
  }
].sort((a, b) => a.logFrameActionStatusReferenceId - b.logFrameActionStatusReferenceId);
```

And then

```
status.forEach(data => {
  console.log('data data data');
  console.log(data);
  console.log('data data data');
  return this.programService.saveStatus(data).subscribe(d => {

  }, error => {
    console.log(error);
  }, () => {
    console.log("succesfully Save");
  })

});
```

Comment: sometimes it was sorted but there is time that it is random

Comment: Would you mind creating a Sample StackBlitz replicating the issue?